# Self-inductance of a coaxial cable with solid core

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance, electromagnetic-induction

Coaxial cable inductance examples are very common in Electromagnetism books and lectures as a simple example to explain self-inductance. In those examples they assume the core is a hollow cylinder, So there is no magnetic flux inside the core, I was wondering what happens if we don't.

[image]

Self-inductance can be calculated from the formula

$$L=\frac{d\phi_B}{di}$$

We can derive $\phi_B$ as following

$$\phi_B= \int_0^a\vec B_{r<a}.\hat n\,ds\quad+\quad \int_a^b\vec B_{a<r<b}.\hat n\,ds$$
$$=\int_0^a\frac{\mu_0J}{2}r\,dr\,+\int_a^b\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}\,dr$$
Where $J$ is the current density in distance $r$ from the center, Which we can assume to be
$$ J=\frac{I}{\pi r^2}$$
$$\phi_B=\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi}(\int_0^a\frac{1}{r}\,dr\,+\,\ln(\frac{a}{b}))$$
But the integral result is $\infty$.

Am I making a mistake in my calculations?

Comment: Where did $J=I/(\pi r^2)$ come from? Don't think that the current density goes to infinity as r approaches zero. For low frequencies, J should be uniform throughout the wire. But for the frequencies that coax lines are generally used at, isn't there a significant skin effect which causes current to flow almost entirely on the surfaces?  Maybe that's why the textbooks assume that the central core is hollow. Also, not sure if you're using the correct expression for B for r<a.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I'm trying to solve it for low frequencies, I used the definition of current density, Electric current per unit area of cross section $I/A$.  We have a total current of $I$ passing through a wire of diameter $a$. Do you mean $J$ should be constant $J=I/\pi a^2$?

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense.